# Codeigniter query builder to join 3 table

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, query-builder

I need your help, i've table like this [image: table]

i want to view detail product when button view with id_product is clicked.
This what i've done .. it seems i need single quote between id_product .. or is there a query builder from codeigniter to achieve this ??

```
function get_detail_product($id_product){
        $query = "SELECT 
        p.id_product, p.product_name, p.price, p.discount, c.category, b.brand_name, p.description, p.spesification, p.picture, p.begin_date, p.end_date, p.qty
        FROM tbl_product as p, tbl_category as c, tbl_brand as b 
        WHERE p.id_Category = c.id_Category and p.id_brand = b.id_brand
        and id_product = ".$id_product;
        return $this->db->query($query);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeIgniter does have a query binder that can achieve something like this. I have not thoroughly looked through your SQL and don't know if it is valid, but a query like that would look something like:

```
$this->db->select('p.id_product, p.product_name, p.price, p.discount, c.category, b.brand_name, p.description, p.spesification, p.picture, p.begin_date, p.end_date, p.qty')
      ->from('tbl_product as p, tbl_category as c, tbl_brand as b')
      ->where('p.id_Category = c.id_Category')
      ->where('p.id_brand = b.id_brand')
      ->where('id_product', $id_product);
      $query = $this->db->get();
      return $query;
```

I am a little unclear at what you are trying to achieve, I did not fully understand the question. Are you just trying to get the query to work, or are looking for advice to try to get all the information together in one row? If you want to join tables you could try something like:

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tbl_product');
    $this->db->join('tbl_category', 'tbl_category.id_category = tbl_products.id_category');
    $this->db->join('tbl_brand', 'tbl_brand.id_brand = tbl_products.id_brand', 'inner');
    $this->db->where('id_product', $id_product);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not returning it correctly. Try this. (not tested)

```
$this->db->select('p.id_product, p.product_name, p.price, p.discount, c.category, b.brand_name, p.description, p.spesification, p.picture, p.begin_date, p.end_date, p.qty');
$this->db->join('tbl_category AS c', 'p.id_Category = c.id_Category');
$this->db->join('tbl_brand AS b', 'p.id_brand = b.id_brand');

$query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_product AS p', array('p.id_product' => $prod_id));

return $query->result_array();
```